Update resource reference of websphere application through Jython script
I am trying to update the resource reference of datasources of a websphere application through jython script rather than providing bindings through applications’ binding XML files.
I have tried below code:
AdminApp.edit(‘my_app’,[‘-MapResEnvRefToRes’,[[ ‘app_module’, ‘jdbc/ref1’,‘jdbc/targetRef’ ]]]

Secondly, I tried to add the -MapResEnvRefToRes as part of command to install application:
AdminConfig.install(path_to_ear,’[-MapResEnvRefToRes,[[ app_module jdbc/ref1 jdbc/targetRef ]]]

Neither of them worked. Can someone help me here.
Thank you very much for your time!
